# How to send on dashboard after facebook logged in using facebook javascript SDK?

Tags: php, api, authentication, facebook-login

I am new to the programming and want to make login with facebook to learn the api integration. I am using php. Below is my code.

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

  FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
   alert("Good you are loged in the app"); // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
       alert("Good you are not authorized to loged in the app");// The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
     alert("Ypu are not loged in the facebook");
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
</script>
```

Above was the code taken from the facebook for login with facebook. It's a readymade code. But below is the my code for login page a conventional login system with php.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * User: Any person
 * Date: 8/7/2016
 * Time: 3:01 PM
 */
?>
<center>
<form name="myLoginForm" method="post" action="session.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email here" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="CANCEL" />
</form>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
<div id="status"></div>
</center>
```

I want that if anyone is logged in using facebook or gets login using the button I have coded should go to the dashbarod.php. But I don't have any idea how to send the person on the dashboard.php only after he is successfully logged in? , since the above code is written in javascript and I don't have so much experience about it.

I tried to implement  in javascript code but its not working.

Also below is the code for my dashoboard.php

```
<?php
/**
 * User: Any person
 * Date: 8/7/2016
 * Time: 3:05 PM
 */
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    header("location:login.php");
else
    require("connection.php");
    $user = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT uname from user WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."' ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($user)) {
        echo "<h1 align='center'>WELCOME ".$row[0]."</h1>";
    }
echo $_SESSION['id'];
echo "<h6 align='right'><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></h6>";
?>
```

Comment: I also want to add logout with facebook too with this.

Comment: read this, and make sure you understand every single line of code: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/